# accessing the files of module using import

Tags: python

I am trying to build a package **test** whose structure is as follows:

```
├── __init__.py
├── p1.py
├── p2.py
└── p3.py
```

I am importing the test in other file as **import test as t**.

So my question is will p1, p2, p3 gets imported by using the above mentioned import. If yes then how can we access them using that way?

Comment: Unless `__init__.py` somehow imports them: no.

Answer (score 0):

By default, no p1,p2 and p3 will not be imported. If you want to use them you could do this

```py
import test.p1 as p1
```

or you could add them to your `__init__.py`

```py
from . import p1
```

then in your code you can do

```py
import test as t

# now you can use p1 here
stuff = t.p1.my_variable
```